# How to deal with arguments in macro names in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

The idea is to setup several fixed CGPoint values with macros, and read them in code flexibly (randomly or with provided integer value)

I have a header file defining several CGPoints value like this:

```
#define kSpawnPoint1 {550,20}
#define kSpawnPoint2 {550,80}
#define kSpawnPoint3 {200,175}
```

I'm generating a random integer in my code between 1 to 3, and plan to read the CGPoint value in the macro according to the integer value. But don't know how to do it. After learning other tutorials about preprocessors, I write my code like following.

```
#define kSpawnPoint1 {550,20}
#define kSpawnPoint2 {550,80}
#define kSpawnPoint3 {200,175}
#define kSpawnPoint(x) kSpawnPoint##x
```

in the m file:

```
int tempInt = 1;
CGPoint tempSpawnPoint = kSpawnPoint(temInt);
```

However it doesn't work.(with warning: undeclared identifier 'kSpawnPointspawnPoint') How can I make this right? And is it the right way to pre-define several CGPoint? I think I must use the preprocessor to achieve this considering future multi-screen resolution support would be easier to implement in macro too, and my kSpawnPoints would not be the same with different screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Macros only operate on text, not the values of variables. When you write `kSpawnPoint(an_int)`, the preprocessor takes the literal string "an_int" and then pastes it, so you end up with `kSpawnPointan_int`. Thus, you would have to put a literal number as the argument in order to end up with one of your points: `kSpawnPoint(1)` -> `kSpawnPoint1` -> `{550, 20}`

To choose randomly among your macros, you will have to put them into a structure that will exist at runtime, like an array or a `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought too. But I seen an example like this:
#define  IS_LEAP_YEAR(y)  y%4==0&&y%100!=0||y%400==0  
int ys=2012;
if(IS_LEAP_YEAR(ys)) {do something}
I've tested it, and it worked fine. So I think macro can take arguments at runtime. What do you think about this?

Comment: That works because you're not trying to use the value of the integer, which is only present at runtime, to create a macro name, which is gone after the preprocessor phase. The result of the macro is a bunch of arithmetic, with the literal variable name pasted in: `if(ys%4==0&&ys%100!=0||ys%400==0)`, as if you had written that code by hand.

Comment: I think I understand this. Thanks, it help me to understand more about how the macro works!

Comment: If you're using Xcode, you can look at the file after preprocessing by going to the Product menu, Perform Action submenu, "Preprocess file". Compiling on the command line, the `-E` flag will stop after the preprocessing step.